# Sound proofing a waste pipe

Tags: pipe, sound-proofing, drain-waste-vent

In our (badly designed) flat the upstairs waste pipes run straight through our bedrooms.

It's a shame as the outer corridor is right next to our bedroom, so it would have been sensible to put it in there.

Any recomendations on sound proofing a waste pipe?

---

EDIT:

Thanks for BMitch's answer, I forgot to add the information that the waste pipe is already enclosed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the pipe is exposed, you can enclose it with a small wall (several 2x4's for the framing and a little drywall).  Make sure at any cleanout openings, you include an access panel in the wall.  Then, before you install the drywall, put a bunch of insulation in there, surrounding the pipe.  Avoid having anything solid connecting the pipe to the wall since that will transmit sound.

Edit: A post construction idea is to hang something that absorbs sound on the wall, such as an acoustical panel frequently used for home theaters or even a tapestry.

Comment: thanks for the advice, sorry I didn't mention that it is already enclosed. But I like the idea of insulation, maybe I could make a small hole and inject some sort of insulation.

Comment: @Alex, In that case, the last two tips still apply, insulation, preferably something like fiber glass, will help.  Though that now means you need to pull down the existing drywall as part of the project.

Comment: Thanks @BMitch, would you suggest the spray insulation (sorry not sure of the correct term). Or would that be too compact and not work for sound proofing?

Comment: @Alex, I think the expanding foam is great for drafts, thermal insulation, and making a sticky mess.  But I have my doubts that it will work well for sound since it forms a connection between the pipe and wall and isn't very compressible.  When we build in high noise environments, our drywall isn't even in direct contact with the studs since they transmit sound (it's attached to a "sound attenuation channel" that's mounted on the stud).

Comment: If you have access from above you may be able to use loose insulation (blown in) and drop it in from above.